# Split Paragraph in Java : Want to store paragraph after particular word address number

Tags: java

I need logic, for example I have

```
String explanation = "The image-search feature will start rolling out in the next few days, said Johanna Wright, a Google search director. \"Every picture has a story, and we want to help you discover that story,\" she said.";
```

The total number of words are 300.

Now I want all strings after word number 150 in a separate string. 
so can you give me logic please

Comment: i have tried out split string but i wan split string after specific word number and i want store it in variable

Comment: @user935988 typically, when we say "what have you tried" it's helpful to show the code you're working with and how you feel it's failing. It gives people a better place to start from, especially when it comes to more difficult or specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

have your tried...

```
explanation.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three things that will be very helpful.

The first is the `String.split(String)` method. It was introduced in Java 6. It works by passing in a regex and splitting the string into tokens based on that regex.

The second is the regex "\s*" which splits on all white space.

The third is a StringBuilder which lets you build strings from other strings without massive rebuilding penalties.

So, first we need to acquire words. We can do that with the split method using our white-space regex.

```
String[] words = String.split("\\s*");
```

From there, it should be rather trivial to count off the first 150 words. You can use a for loop that starts at 150 and moves up from there.

```
String sentence = "";
for(int i = 150; i < words.length; i++) {
    sentence = sentence + words[i] + " ";
}
```

But this is very expensive because it rebuilds the string so much. We can make it better by doing this

```
StringBuilder sentence = "";
for(int i = 150; i < words.length; i++) {
    sentence.append(words[i]).append(" ");
}
```

But it all together and wa-bam, you have your sentence formatted as you want. (Just watch out for that extra space on the end!)

Comment: By the way, I'm not going to lie. This is something that comes from just working with the Java libraries. I highly recommend taking some time to learn some of the basic APIs of Java, like `String` and the various `Collection`s being some very basic ones.

Comment: its working thank you so much but its giving space between two character Ex"s m a r t p h o n e s ,  l i k e  v o i c e  a n d  i m a g e  s e a r c h " so how can remove this space

Answer (score 0):

One way would be `explanation.replaceFirst("(\\S+\\s*){0,150}", "")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to iterate over words as in example,

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(context);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // if regexMatcher.groupCount()%150 == 0 then build the next string list
}
```